# Python matching group is consuming text and preventing other matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract all text from a html file. I know there are packages like Beautiful Soup but I wanted to try something simple. Also BS does not properly convert this to text. It concatenates them without a space.

I tried to use

```
re.findall('>([^<\n]+?)(?:<[^<]*?>)',letter_html)
```

but if there are two pieces of text separated by only one tag like

```
DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH&nbsp;<br>AND HUMAN SERVICES
```

only the first string is found. How can I get around this.

Comment: I think you may be confused about the meaning of "non-capturing group". It does not have any effect on the actual text matching; it just means that you can't refer back to that value for further extraction or replacement.

Comment: _...but I wanted to try something simple._ So why don't you use `BeautifulSoup.get_text()`? Parsing HTML with regex is never good idea.

Comment: XPath `//text()`, loop, and concatenate with a space. What more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>([^<\n]+?)(?=<[^<]*?>)
```

I just needed to use a lookahead since it doesn't consume text.